# How is the  ViewState used to save a value in browser?

Tags: asp.net

I set ASP.Net ViewState to off for a text box control, but the value for the name of the user is still there. Why is this so?

Comment: `but still in text box i see the name of user` If you check the source code, you probably still have `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />`

Comment: Yes i have. But this time i used a different username. how come it is saved when the viewstate is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

> View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there to persist state across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state is the property values of the controls that make up its control hierarchy.) This begs the question, "What sort of state needs to be persisted?" To answer that question, let's start by looking at what state doesn't need to be persisted across postbacks. Recall that in the instantiation stage of the page life cycle, the control hierarchy is created and those properties that are specified in the declarative syntax are assigned. Since these declarative properties are automatically reassigned on each postback when the control hierarchy is constructed, there's no need to store these property values in the view state.

like balexandre already posted

Answer (score 1):

ViewState cannot be modified by the browser, as the browser has no knowledge of what viewstate is. It's merely a snapshot of what was sent to the client and will be interrogated once the form is post back to the server.

Have a look at the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) to get a better understanding of what ViewState is

Answer (score 1):

In a simple answer: **Yes**

But you should read all about View State as it's important to undertsand it and not thinking that things automagical work.

> [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)